# Play! Framework - SaaS subdomain name filter

Tags: java, playframework, saas

I know this question has been asked quite a few times, however, I have a different approach of what I want to achieve.

[Since Play 1.1, you're able to match hosts.](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1.1/releasenotes-1.1#routeHost) This is very useful, however, it means that for every controller, I will need to pass through the `subdomain` route param. This is quite a burden and repeatful if I have hundreds of controllers which use the `subdomain` param.

Is there not a way to create a filter which looks at the host name before everything else is executed and then sets an on-the-fly config value for that request?

For example (brainstorming), a filter would do the following:

```
    // use request host, but hard-coded for now...
    String host = "test.example.com";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([a-z0-9]+)\\.example\\.com$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(host);
    if (m.matches()) {
        // OUT: test
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.setProperty("host", m.group(1));
    }
```

And in the models I'd do something like `System.getProperty("host");`

I know this isn't how it should be done, but I'm just brainstorming.

At least with this way:

1. I don't have to pass the `subdomain` param through to every
   controller.
2. I don't have to pass the `subdomain` param through to any models
   either
3. Models have direct access to the `subdomain` value so I can filter out objects that belong to the client

Also, I'm aware that `System.setProperty()` always applies to the entire JVM; which is a problem. I only want this value to be available throughout the duration of the request. What should I use?

Let's analyse. How would you do it?  What would be a good approach? Is this possible with Play?  I'm sure there are quite a few running into this problem. Your input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are close.  If I had to do this, I would write a controller annotated with `@Before` and have that method extract the hostname from the request headers and put it in renderArgs.

Something like this (I haven't tested it):

```
public class HostExtractor extends Controller {

    @Before
    public static void extractHost() {
       // Code to read from request headers and extract whatever you need here.
       String host = 'Your Code Here'
       renderArgs.put("hostname", host);
    }
}
```

Then, in your other controllers, you tell it you want to use that controller above as a filter.

```
@With(HostExtractor.class)
public class MyController extends Controller {

    public static void homepage() {
        String hostname = renderArgs.get("host", String.class);
        // Do whatever logic you need to render the page here.
    }
}
```

Again, I haven't tested this, but I'm doing something similar to cache objects in memcache.  I hope that helps!

Comment: Hi @Todd - thank you for your answer. This is a much better approach. Is there a way I can get a config property accesible in a model instead? If not, then i'll accept this solution.

Comment: I've just read this post, maybe i'll go down this route: http://www.lunatech-research.com/archives/2011/03/04/play-framework-writing-multitenancy-application-hibernate-filters